# Writing a DELETE query for 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to write a simply query that will delete an event based off its event_id. That event_id could be in 1 of 3 tables in a database however.

Leagues
Tournaments
Trainings

Each event_id is generated by a randomizer function so each id is unique.

I have tried a few different syntaxs for SQL but none of them will actually delete the event from the DB table. Any suggestions?

Here is what I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
   
    $query = "delete from leagues where event_id= '$event_id', delete from tournaments where event_id= '$event_id', delete from trainings where event_id= '$event_id'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
    header('location: index_admin.php');
    
    
} else {
   
}
```

I have also tried using the union command, using multiple delete queries, putting a semicolon after each delete command. What else can I try?

Comment: Just make this three separate delete statements that you run one after the other.

Comment: The syntax of your query is wrong: you can't just string together three queries separated by commas, but more than that, you don't seem to have initialised `$event_id`, so your query won't include the ID to delete.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you mean like this: $query = "delete from leagues where event_id='$event_id' delete from tournaments where event_id='$event_id' delete from trainings where event_id='$event_id'";?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Sorry I didnt capture the full page, I do have $event_id initialized higher up. The query works when I only target 1 DB table, I just need to be able to target all 3 in one query.

Comment: I mean this: `$query = "delete from leagues where event_id ='$event_id'"`. Then: `$query = "delete from tournaments where event_id ='$event_id'"`. At last: `$query = "delete from trainings where event_id ='$event_id'"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('delete from leagues where event_id = :event_id');
    $stmt->execute([ ':event_id' => $event_id]);
    $res = $stmt->fetch();
    header('location: index_admin.php');
}else{
   
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous, susceptible to SQL injection: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

No reason to execute 3 separate DELETEs.

```sql
DELETE leagues, tournaments, trainings
FROM (SELECT $event_id AS event_id) src -- use parameter instead of immediate insert
LEFT JOIN leagues USING (event_id)
LEFT JOIN tournaments USING (event_id)
LEFT JOIN trainings USING (event_id)
```

Of course you'd not insert the value into the query like above - you'd use prepared statement.